# Function stuck in infinite loop, cannot find reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, infinite-loop

The code is supposed to take each pixel rgb value and store it in a 2d array (e.g. pixels[pixelNumber][r, g, b]), where it then gets sent to a user defined method to, in this case, blur it (using Gaussian blur). Width and height are pixel width and height definitions taken from the image, and radius is the user defined radius of which pixels get averaged to be blurred.
It gave me a divide by 0 error at

```
weight_r = pixels[j][0] * weight
weight_g = pixels[j][1] * weight
weight_b = pixels[j][2] * weight
```

before I changed total_weight from 0 to 1 when defined just below the first for loop, if that helps

```
def blur(pixels, radius, width, height):
    for i in range(len(pixels)):
        total_weight = 1
        pix_weight = 0
        r_temp = radius
        pixels_2 = copy.deepcopy(pixels)
        x = i % width
        y = (i // width) + 1
        for j in range(len(pixels)):
            x_2 = j % width
            y_2 = (j // width) + 1
            dist = math.sqrt(((x_2 - x) ** 2) + ((y_2 - y) ** 2))
            while(r_temp > 0):
                if((x_2 - radius == x or x_2 + radius == x) and (y_2 - radius == y or y_2 + radius == y) and dist != 0):
                    weight = ((math.e ** (-((dist ** 2) / (2 * (radius ** 2))))) / (2 * math.pi * (radius ** 2)))
                    total_weight = total_weight + weight
                    weight_r = pixels[j][0] * weight
                    weight_g = pixels[j][1] * weight
                    weight_b = pixels[j][2] * weight
                    pix_weight = pix_weight + weight_r + weight_g + weight_b
                r_temp = r_temp - 1
        final_blur = int((pix_weight / total_weight) / 255)
        pixels_2[i][0] = int(pixels[i][0] * final_blur)
        pixels_2[i][1] = int(pixels[i][1] * final_blur)
        pixels_2[i][2] = int(pixels[i][2] * final_blur)
    return pixels_2
```

Method above, pixels is a 2d array, radius, width, and height are all integers.

Comment: Since you it's not a recursive method, you should have been stucked in the `while` loop.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar I am using r_temp = r_temp - 1 though, shouldn't that eventually lower it to 0 and close the while loop?

Comment: I cannot reproduce an infinite loop with this code. For various list-of-lists for `pixels`, and compatible radius, width, and height arguments, it terminates as expected and produces a result. What is the exact set of arguments you are calling it with?

Comment: add `print(r_temp)` and watch what it does I think you have a huge number of pixels so this is just taking too long

Comment: @ChrisFaffler Infinite loop or long computing time ?

Comment: @ely I am using an input from an image for pixels, width, and height, (width and height are both 256), radius value of 1.

Comment: @scharette I've given it over 30 minutes now, still has not completed.

Comment: @percusse I set radius (and therefore r_temp) to 2 as an input, put in print(r_temp) right before r_temp = r_temp - 1 and it prints out 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 over and over.

Comment: What is `len(pixels)`? You might want to put in a line that prints out progress every 1% or so of pixels. Then you'll see if it's looping or just taking a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied your code exactly, using Python 2.7.11 with some example arguments below, and I cannot reproduce an infinite loop. For which arguments are you seeing infinite loop behavior?

```
In [13]: p = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
              [1, 1, 1, 1 ,1], 
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

In [14]: r = 3

In [15]: w, h = 5, 5

In [16]: blur(p, r, w, h)
Out[16]: 
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

(On a separate note, it looks like your blur kernel is not treating the different image boundaries with the same edge conditions).

*Added* you mentioned in the comments you are using a 256x256 image -- and also just to check on the format I tried making an example with `256 ** 2` entries (list of all pixels), where each pixel is a 3-element list. I see now this is probably what you were going for.

Those changes are in this example:

```
In [19]: p = [[1, 1, 1] for _ in range(256 ** 2)]

In [20]: %timeit blur(p, 1, 256, 256)
```

This indeed is taking a very long time to run, I'll update with time info when it's finished.

Comment: I am seeing the infinite loop behavior in the while loop. I am on python 3, if that matters.

Also could you elaborate on your last statement? I'm kinda new to coding

Comment: @ChrisFaffler No, it is not infinite looping. It's just taking a _long_ time.

Comment: That is a much bigger scope question. The basic idea will be to get rid of the modulus stuff and just iterate over height and width. Right now you're doing an N^2 double loop, where N is _the number of pixels!_ This means you're doing a loop of M^4 where M is the side length (if it is a square image). You want to reduce this to be close to the order of H x W for the height and width (since your radius is 1).

Comment: You are correct, I added print(i) just below the first for loop and print(j) just below the second loop, with the width and height values of 256, it loops through the second for loop _65536_ times per each of the 1st's loops, which then needs to loop _65536_ times. I guess my code is just _really_ slow and not stuck in an infinite loop. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The radius will not be bound to 1, it will be user defined. How would I go about reducing the size of the second loop?

Comment: My advice would be to first research some blur kernel algorithms (or basic convolution algorithm) to get a rough sense about how this is done. Then when you have made a first attempt at it, come back and open a separate question to ask about any specific parts of convolution that are blocking your understanding.

Comment: One other optimization would be to create the entire value of `pixels_2` outside of the loop, before you start, with `copy.deepcopy` of all of `pixels`. Then inside the loops, you'll have to use both i and j indices when writing into that output copy. At least this will take the copying outside of the loop.

Comment: `(x_2 - radius == x or x_2 + radius == x)` can be summarized as `abs(x_2 - x) == radius` (same for y portion). Also, I believe `dist != 0` is implied by the other two conditionals on that `if` line. If `dist` is 0 but one of the other items is true, then radius == 0, which you could just prevent at the start the function by exiting early or something.